# NumberFormatException while trying to authorize user

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set up small web application in spring using bootrap and thymeleaf. I have no idea what's going on, because I have already one user in databe and I'm trying to log on it. When I pass wrong credentials is okey and spring-security doesn't pass me futher. But, when I pass corrent credentials, there is a NumberFormatException exception thrown from spring-security-core saing that it cannot parse my password to double. Password is hashed by BCrypt, but even when it wasn't hashed I had the same problem.

The exeption occurs in DaoAuthorizationProvider when is trying to getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username).

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: For input string: "$2a$10$jVoJ2TnQkTLKYn/j.ENlcemM90ap/MoZNUAGvsR9eMuL4P6uayCGG"
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$2a$10$jVoJ2TnQkTLKYn/j.ENlcemM90ap/MoZNUAGvsR9eMuL4P6uayCGG"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.getDouble(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:238) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.result.BooleanValueFactory.createFromBytes(BooleanValueFactory.java:113) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.result.BooleanValueFactory.createFromBytes(BooleanValueFactory.java:46) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeByteArray(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:133) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getBoolean(ResultSetImpl.java:678) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getBoolean(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$1.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:234) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$1.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:228) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:678) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:616) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:699) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:762) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:227) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:184) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

My WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select id, login as principal, pass as credentials from user where login=?").passwordEncoder(dPasswordEncoder());
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/marks",true)
                .permitAll();
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager() throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setUseReferer(true);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder dPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Login page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>RODO</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand"></a> <img src="../images/icon.png" width="64" height="64" th:src="@{images/icon.png}"/>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${errorMsg}">
        Podanego użytkownika nie ma w systemie.
    </div>
    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px">Podaj numer indeksu lub identyfikator</h1>
    <form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px">Logowanie</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Nazwa użytkownika</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                   placeholder="nazwa użytkownika">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Hasło</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="hasło">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Zaloguj</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I was using this configuration before and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From javadoc of method `setUsersByUsernameQuery` :

> Allows the default query string used to retrieve users based on username to be
>        * overridden, if default table or column names need to be changed. The default query
>        * is {@link #DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY}; when modifying this query, ensure that all
>        * returned columns are mapped back to the same column positions as in the default query.
>        * If the 'enabled' column does not exist in the source database, a permanent true
>        * value for this column may be returned by using a query similar to
>   * **select username,password,'true' as enabled from users where username = ?**

Is it correct, that you pass in sql query password as third parameter?

Comment: No, it wasn't correct. I had to change parameters order and add authorities. Like this .usersByUsernameQuery("select login as principal, pass as credentials, true from user where login=?").passwordEncoder(dPasswordEncoder())
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user.login as principal, user.permission as role from user where login=?");