# Spring Security dosn't decrypt password, returning 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm looking for help as didn't find any working solution for my problem. I assuming this got something to do with Spring Security 5. spring getting a password from a call but don't know what to do with him (this is how I understand error). So my files are:

JWTAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
@Override
public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest request,
        ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain
) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest)request);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
}
}
```

JWTLoginFilter.java

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
public JWTLoginFilter(
        String url,
        AuthenticationManager authManager
) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
    setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
}
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res
)   throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    creds.getUsername(),
                    creds.getPassword(),
                    Collections.emptyList()
            )
    );
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
}
}
```

TokenAuthenticationService.java

```
static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, String username) {
    String JWT = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(username)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
            .compact();
    res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
    String resMessage = "{"+"\"bearer_token\":\""+JWT+"\"}";
    try{res.getOutputStream().write(resMessage.getBytes());}catch(Exception e){}
}

static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
    if (token != null) {
        // parse the token.
        String user = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();

        return user != null ?
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList()) :
                null;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

private final String USER_QUERY = "SELECT alias, email, password FROM users WHERE email=?";
private final String ROLES_QUERY = "SELECT alias, role, email FROM users WHERE email=?";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*/")
            .antMatchers("/eureka/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery(USER_QUERY)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY);

}
}
```

And my error code is:

    `2019-12-05 14:15:22.930 ERROR 21180 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.a.gateway.security.JWTLoginFilter    : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.`

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: For input string: "$2y$12$Pq..wyjRZBlgRoJp./Eb7uCN3KZ4YEtV2r4hAl2w7ynCzb6SulHoi"
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.armadillo.armadilloone.gateway.security.JWTLoginFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTLoginFilter.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$2y$12$Pq..wyjRZBlgRoJp./Eb7uCN3KZ4YEtV2r4hAl2w7ynCzb6SulHoi"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.getDouble(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:238) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.result.BooleanValueFactory.createFromBytes(BooleanValueFactory.java:107) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.result.BooleanValueFactory.createFromBytes(BooleanValueFactory.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeByteArray(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:133) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:1270) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getBoolean(ResultSetImpl.java:663) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getBoolean(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager.lambda$loadUsersByUsername$0(JdbcUserDetailsManager.java:155) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:763) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcUserDetailsManager.java:150) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:181) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

I try to understand reason why this not working, debuging line by line but still not sucess. I've look for different solution there on SO but nothing seems to works. If you have any other idea or know why it's not working, why can't decode password, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware that the method userByUsernameQuery requires query in a specific order with specific data. When I fix this it starts working. Helpfull was information from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614715/numberformatexception-while-trying-to-authorize-user). Correct sql query for jdbcAuthentication is `SELECT email, password, active FROM users where email = ?`